# Setting up graphql yoga with websockets in nextjs api

Tags: websocket, next.js, graphql, subscription

In graphql yoga documentation, I found [this example](https://www.the-guild.dev/graphql/yoga-server/docs/features/subscriptions#subscriptions-over-websockets-with-graphql-ws) for using graphql yoga with websockets but it's in nodejs environment. How can I setup a server in nextjs api using this example? All advice is appreciated, thanks.

```js
import { createServer } from '@graphql-yoga/node'
import { WebSocketServer } from 'ws'
import { useServer } from 'graphql-ws/lib/use/ws'
 
async function main() {
  const yogaApp = createServer({
    graphiql: {
      // Use WebSockets in GraphiQL
      subscriptionsProtocol: 'WS'
    }
  })
 
  // Get NodeJS Server from Yoga
  const httpServer = await yogaApp.start()
  // Create WebSocket server instance from our Node server
  const wsServer = new WebSocketServer({
    server: httpServer,
    path: yogaApp.getAddressInfo().endpoint
  })
 
  // Integrate Yoga's Envelop instance and NodeJS server with graphql-ws
  useServer(
    {
      execute: (args: any) => args.rootValue.execute(args),
      subscribe: (args: any) => args.rootValue.subscribe(args),
      onSubscribe: async (ctx, msg) => {
        const { schema, execute, subscribe, contextFactory, parse, validate } =
          yogaApp.getEnveloped(ctx)
 
        const args = {
          schema,
          operationName: msg.payload.operationName,
          document: parse(msg.payload.query),
          variableValues: msg.payload.variables,
          contextValue: await contextFactory(),
          rootValue: {
            execute,
            subscribe
          }
        }
 
        const errors = validate(args.schema, args.document)
        if (errors.length) return errors
        return args
      }
    },
    wsServer
  )
}
 
main().catch((e) => {
  console.error(e)
  process.exit(1)
})
```

Comment: thanks for asking this question! It actually inspired us to create a new example showcasing how to set up Next.js with GraphQL Yoga and have subscriptions run over WebSockets, do check it out here: https://the-guild.dev/graphql/yoga-server/docs/integrations/integration-with-nextjs#websockets-for-subscriptions. Hope this helps!